# Handling Application Closing Calls from Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I've added code for the Closing event on my main window which works for clicking on the X, and it is able to cancel the event without an issue (it runs through a "are you sure? Make sure to save" type dialog and closing events)

Unfortunately, if I double-click on the icon it hits my breakpoint on the `RibbonWindow_Closing` event, but when `e.Cancel` is set to true it closes out anyway, as if its being called by `Application.Current.Shutdown()`

Alt-F4 (and icon -> close) and the X button are both being handled correctly, but not double-clicking on the icon itself

Does anyone know why this would occur? I am using Prism and the main window is created by a bootstrapper if it matters.

Here is the stack trace, its all external code besides hitting my RibbonWindow_Closing event:

```
MyProgram.exe!MyProgram.Shell.RibbonWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) Line 64  C#
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) + 0x91 bytes
```

> 

```
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.WmClose() + 0x96 bytes  
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.WindowFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0xe5 bytes 
 PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.PublicHooksFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x7e bytes    
 WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0xbe bytes   
 WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) + 0x7d bytes   
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x53 bytes    
 WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x42 bytes   
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0xb4 bytes   
 WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) + 0x104 bytes   
 [Native to Managed Transition] 
 [Managed to Native Transition] 
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.InternalClose(bool shutdown, bool ignoreCancel) + 0xa1 bytes   
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.DoShutdown() + 0x1b6 bytes    
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.ShutdownImpl() + 0x1c bytes   
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.ShutdownCallback(object arg) + 0x5 bytes  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x53 bytes 
 WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x42 bytes   
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() + 0x8d bytes
```

Testing RibbonWindow, gives Message but still Closes

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="MyProject.TestShell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Title="TestShell" Height="300" Width="300" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

This works as a regular window, Get the message and it stays open:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.TestShell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestShell" Height="300" Width="300" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind is simple:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    MessageBox.Show("No close!");
}
```

**Update**

Ok I narrowed it down to being an issue with the RibbonWindow control, apparently it shutsdown the application when the icon is double-clicked.

Apparently it also closes the main application if a sub-window is closed in this same fashion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3e9cdc9c-dfb7-49f2-923a-ead07504d568

```
/// <summary>
///   This handles the click events on the window icon.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Click event sender</param>
/// <param name="e">event args</param>
private void IconMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        if (SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenuCommand.CanExecute(null, this))
        {
            SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenuCommand.Execute(null, this);
        }
    }
    else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        if (ApplicationCommands.Close.CanExecute(null, this))
        {
            ApplicationCommands.Close.Execute(null, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No repro, hard to guess at.  Show a stack trace.

Comment: @HansPassant I wish I could... it goes from [External Code] to my Closing event. Sender is my Shell window and the first thing I do is set (CancelEventArgs e) e.Cancel = true. Do you mean Repro = Reproduce? So you are able to cancel out of closing when double-clicking on the top left icon?

Comment: @HansPassant I had to disable debugging just my code, updated OP.

Comment: It's being closed by the Application, note DoShutdown() in the trace.  Any "First chance exception" notification in the Output window?

Comment: @HansPassant none after it is finished loading and usable. The first thing I did after opening the application was double-click the icon to close it. I noticed it was sending that DoShutdown() in the trace, but how can I prevent that, or is there no way to do so? I'm able to catch 4/5 of the ways the program can be closed (Exit button in menu, Icon -> Close, Alt + F4, X button on right).

Comment: This just isn't supposed to happen, the window should be the first to get the notification, *then* the app shuts down because there are no windows left.  I can't explain the stack trace if you did this by double-clicking the icon.  Try another machine.

Comment: @HansPassant I have a feeling its a (bug?) issue regarding the RibbonWindow itself. I created a new Shell as a Window with nothing in it but an empty DockPanel. Double-Clicking the icon gave me a messagebox and stopped closing. I converted it into a RibbonWindow and now I get the message, but it closes anyway. Are you able to test the RibbonWindow? I've added my test shell window code to the OP, do you have the same result with a RibbonWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I narrowed it down to being an issue with the RibbonWindow control, apparently it shutsdown the application when the icon is double-clicked.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3e9cdc9c-dfb7-49f2-923a-ead07504d568

```
/// <summary>
///   This handles the click events on the window icon.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Click event sender</param>
/// <param name="e">event args</param>
private void IconMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        if (SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenuCommand.CanExecute(null, this))
        {
            SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenuCommand.Execute(null, this);
        }
    }
    else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        if (ApplicationCommands.Close.CanExecute(null, this))
        {
            ApplicationCommands.Close.Execute(null, this);
        }
    }
}
```

I found the solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9955b191-13d5-4986-a5c0-e73f50a44b44

which was to register my own ApplicationClosing command such as:

```
[Export]
public partial class TestShell : RibbonWindow
{
    public TestShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(TestShell), new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, CloseApplicationExecuted));
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Not closing 1!");
    }

    private static void CloseApplicationExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        RibbonWindow window = sender as RibbonWindow;
        if (window != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not closing 2!");
            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I double-click the icon I get "Not closing 2!", and any other closing method I get "Not closing 1!"

Hopefully this can save someone the hours it took me to figure it out. Thank you Hans for helping me diagnose the issue.

Update: If you want the CloseApplicationExecuted to fire the same event as regular closing, just call

```
private static void CloseApplicationExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        RibbonWindow window = sender as RibbonWindow;
        if (window != null)
        {
            args.Handled = true;
            window.Close();
        }
    }
```